# Why is the window description coming like this when I press Super key?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

[image: Window description problem]

The window title should appear beneath the window, not on the top. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in an option I had activated in gnome-tweak-tool. It's in extensions and named Native Window Placement. When it was activated the behavior which has been captured in the image was shown. It is meant to arrange windows in a compact manner. When it is deactivated, the window title text takes up space and places it beneath which is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

try adjusting some custom settings in "settings manager" -> "windows manager" / "windows manager tweaks" / "appearance"

Many ways to customize the look/style etc...

Comment: Do you mean the "Onboard settings" ?

Comment: no - i believe "onboard settings" is a keyboard map/macros for on-screen keyboards...     I am referring to the general settings gui. Depending on your distro the names may vary slightly.

Comment: Oh i got what the problem was. In the tweak-tool I had activated the native window placement option and this was causing the problem.